# Regex match fraction for HTML5 pattern

Tags: regex, html

How could I match fraction which has exactly 3 digits in the numerator and exactly 2 in the denominator

This is what I have tried but does not seem to work:

```
[0-9]?(\d*[/])?\d+
```

Comment: As in 3 digits in the numerator, and 2 in the denominator?

Comment: Try `[0-9]{3}/[0-9]{2}` if you mean to match fractions like `234/23`.

Comment: @Druzion yes a number

Comment: @Druzion: Why did you remove the `html5` tag
?

Comment: @krushiovida: Is the pattern for the `pattern` attribute?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Because it is not used in HTML5 as far as I am aware. If anything, it should maybe have the [tag:javascript] tag? Edit: I forgot the `pattern` attribute, I'll add the [tag:html5] back....

Comment: If the regex is to be used with HTML5 pattern attribute there is no need using `^` and `$`. They are added automatically. Although they do not harm, just imagine how `^(?:^\d{3}/\d{2}$)$` looks :)

Comment: Yes pattern attribute

Comment: @krushiovida: Cool, then use what I suggested above or Druzion's regex (with or without `^`/`$`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
^\d{3}/\d{2}$
```

It will select a numerator with 3 digits, and denominator with 2.

`\d` is shorthand for `[0-9]`, so it will match any digit. The `{3}` quantifier repeats this `3` times, so `\d{3}` is equivalent to `\d\d\d`.

`^` is the start of a line/string, and `$` is the end. This makes sure it does not capture something like `123/1234`

<kbd>[**Live Demo on Regex101**](https://regex101.com/r/cJ3rL6/1)</kbd>

---

Note that if this is being used in the `pattern` attribute, you do not need the `^` and `$`:

```
\d{3}/\d{2}
```

```html
<input pattern="\d{3}/\d{2}" title="3 Digits in the Numerator, 2 in the Denominator">
<input type="submit">
```

Comment: you need to enclose it otherwise it will consider `123/1234` also

Comment: @Braj Not necessarily. No need to escape `/`, BTW.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew please can you explain me a bit more.